# Problems after deleting ElementaryOS Desktop installed on Ubuntu

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tty

Today I just tried out Pa(n)theon DE (PDE of ElementaryOS) and it messed up a little bit. But the most important thing is, the PDE created its own terminal, and when I remove it (=PDE), I think it removed the gnome-terminal and also its own one. There's still a Terminal logo in the application menu but when I click it, the cursor is just a loading cursor, and then nothing happens. My alternative terminal is now to use the one in VS Code. How can I fix it?

I googled for solution and they said I should switch to TTY windows using Ctrl + Alt + Fx (x from 1 to 7). But on PDE I accidently set Ctrl + Alt to be language switching shortcut, so now Ctrl + Alt is the same as Ctrl alone. Also many keyboard shortcuts are messed up now and some programs messed up (For example my Minecraft Launcher when launched appears and disappers instantly).

I know that Linux distros are file-based, so how/where can I edit those shortcut? Should I reinstall completly GNOME?

Comment: Perhaps you can boot a live session, chroot and then reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`...

Comment: Do you have any tutorial?

Comment: Not that hard to Google: http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/07/creating-chroot-ubuntu.html

Comment: Or is it ok if I install `unity` desktop instead, or use `unity` to reinstall `gnome`, or upgrade it?

Comment: That depends on your actual Ubuntu release.

Comment: I'm using 18.04.2 LTS btw

Comment: Then it's preferably as I suggested, you can install Unity later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94732/discussion-between-infrustration-and-gabrielagarcia).